# Validate XSD with XML 

Tags: java, xml, xsd

I want to know how to validate XML with XSD . XML is not of an element type but a complex type . Since validator class's validate method compare only element type.

So basically I want to valide XSD's complex type with an XML.

e.g.

**Basic XSD below**

```
xs:element name="Customer">
  <xs:complexType>
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="Dob" type="xs:date" />
      <xs:element name="Address">
        <xs:complexType>
          <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="Line1" type="xs:string" />
            <xs:element name="Line2" type="xs:string" />
          </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
      </xs:element>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

We can assume we have multiple complex type in the Customer element.

**MY XML is**

```
<Address> 
    <Line1>34 thingy street, someplace</Line1> 
    <Line2>sometown, w1w8uu </Line2>
</Address>
```

How I validate my XML with XSD.
Kindly post your suggestions in java

Comment: "Kindly post your suggestions in java" is a nice way of saying "give me the codez", but in essence it's still the same. Please post your own code next time along with an explanation where you are stuck, so people see that you are not just being lazy.

Comment: Hi Tomalak, Its not about being lazy. There are features, which are available in one language and not in others. One can give a solution in other language which might not possible in java.

Comment: What have you tried, what errors do you get? `Validator.validate()` does validate xml against schemas, so what else do you need?

Answer (score 1):

Something like

```
import javax.xml.validation.Schema;
import javax.xml.validation.SchemaFactory;
import javax.xml.validation.Validator;

//  .....


    try {
        File xmlFile // read XML file

        File xsdFile // read XSD file

        Schema schema = SchemaFactory.newInstance(XMLConstants.W3C_XML_SCHEMA_NS_URI).newSchema(xsdFile);
        Validator validator = schema.newValidator();
        validator.validate(new StreamSource(xmlFile));
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (SAXException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```