# How to compare document objects in java with .xsd files?

Tags: java, xml, xsd, document, jdom

I am trying to compare Document objects to understand if they are well formed or not. So to do that, I made a research about it and heard that xsd files are used to make this comparison. Can you please give me some basci examples to compare document with using xsd objcets ?

For example what do I have to write into xsd file and how I can compare it with a Document object ?

Thank you all

Comment: Your Question is already answered here: [Validate XSD with XML][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3022006/validate-xsd-with-xml

Comment: Thanks a lot its my fault I did not see.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need an XSD schema to determine if a document is well-formed. You only need it to determine if the document is valid against the schema.

I'm not sure what you mean by "comparing XML documents". What are you comparing them with?